# JQuery .clone() and .appendTo() causing multiple appends

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone, appendto

So I've read numerous similar questions and answers - none seem to address this specific issue.  So here goes.

Consider the following code:

```
<body>
<script>

    function addAttendee() {
        $('.newAttendee').clone().appendTo('.attendees');
    }

</script>

<form action="test2.php" name="testform" method="post">
    <span class="attendees">
    <input type="text" name="attendee[0][city]" value="city 1">
    <input type="text" name="attendee[0][state]" value="state 1">
    <input type="text" name="attendee[0][zip]" value="zip 1">
    </span>
<a href="#" name="addAttendee" onclick="addAttendee()">Add Attendee</a>
<br>
<input type="submit" onclick="getOutput()">
</form>

<div class="hideThis" style="display: none;">
    <span class="newAttendee">
        <br>
    <input type="text" name="attendee[1][city]" value="city 2">
    <input type="text" name="attendee[1][state]" value="state 2">
    <input type="text" name="attendee[1][zip]" value="zip 2">
    </span>
</div>
```

When I click "Add Attendee" the first time, I get what I want.  But each subsequent click on that link causes double the previous inserted sections to be inserted.  First click 1, second 2, third 4, etc.

Am I missing something?

Thanks to all in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `$('.newAttendee').clone()` will clone all elements with that class

Try using `first()` or `last()` to only clone one of them

```
$('.newAttendee').first().clone().appendTo('.attendees');
```

Comment: You could better use $('.newAttendee').clone()..removeClass('newAttendee').appendTo('.attendees');

Comment: @SideriteZackwehdex but that might have an impact on css or other code . It's very simple to only clone one of them

Comment: I think the intention of the code was not to add spans with the newAttendee class, but only use the one as a template. If not, then you are right.

Comment: @SideriteZackwehdex either way cloning only one will work. Can also store a clone when page loads.

Comment: @charlietfl Bingo. That did it.  Makes sense.  I was under the (false) impression that clone only copied the existing section one time.  I see now where I was wrong.  Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `$('.newAttendee')` select all elments with class  newAttendee. 
And after you clone it you have 2 and so on.
Changing the class after cloning would avoid this.