# How to change a single part of an input "name" using JQuery/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

As a follow up to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36103849/jquery-clone-and-appendto-causing-multiple-appends), considering this code:

```
<body>
<script>

    function addAttendee() {
        $('.newAttendee').first().clone().appendTo('.attendees');
    }

</script>

<form action="test2.php" name="testform" method="post">
    <span class="attendees">
    <input type="text" name="attendee[0][city]" value="city 1">
    <input type="text" name="attendee[0][state]" value="state 1">
    <input type="text" name="attendee[0][zip]" value="zip 1">
    </span>
<a href="#" name="addAttendee" onclick="addAttendee()">Add Attendee</a>
<br>
<input type="submit" onclick="getOutput()">
</form>

<div class="hideThis" style="display: none;">
    <span class="newAttendee">
        <br>
    <input type="text" name="attendee[1][city]" value="city 2">
    <input type="text" name="attendee[1][state]" value="state 2">
    <input type="text" name="attendee[1][zip]" value="zip 2">
    </span>
</div>

</body>
```

When I click "Add Attendee", I'd like to change the array number of the added section to the next higher value.

I.e.:

```
name="attendee[1][xxxxx]
```

needs to become

```
name="attendee[2][xxxxx]
```

Wondering if anyone has any shortcuts to this?

Thanks again, in advance.

Comment: Adding a comment as to why you downvoted would be helpful.  If I'm being "stupid" I'd like to know that and why.

Answer (score 0):

Would be simpler to not assign an index value in the array names:

For example change :

```
<input type="text" name="attendee[1][city]" value="city 2">
```

To

```
<input type="text" name="attendee[][city]" value="city 2">
```

Also since you are cloning existing ones you should reset the values in clones

```
function addAttendee() {
    var $clone = $('.newAttendee').first().clone();
    $clone.find('input').val('');
    $('.attendees').append($clone);       
}
```

Comment: Yes.. the values are actually just there so I can see them as being different when testing.  Ultimately I won't use them.  Guess I should have said that.  My apologies.

Comment: This just creates a long array with duplicate indexes for "city", "state", etc.  what I'm looking for is an array of arrays that contains an attendee.

Comment: Correction.. this creates a new array of numeric arrays with each field being it's own numeric array..

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that worked for what I wanted to do:

```
<body>
<script>

    $(document).ready( function() {
    });

    $attendeeValue = 1;

    function addAttendee() {
        var $newAttendee = $('.newAttendee').html();
        $newAttendee = $newAttendee.replace(/xxx/g,$attendeeValue++);
        console.log($newAttendee);
        $('.attendees').append($newAttendee);
        //$('.newAttendee').first().clone().appendTo('.attendees');

    }

</script>

<form action="test2.php" name="testform" method="post">
    <span class="attendees">
    <input type="text" name="attendee[0][city]" value="city 1">
    <input type="text" name="attendee[0][state]" value="state 1">
    <input type="text" name="attendee[0][zip]" value="zip 1">
    </span>
<a href="#" name="addAttendee" onclick="addAttendee()">Add Attendee</a>
<br>
<input type="submit" onclick="getOutput()">
</form>

<div class="hideThis" style="display: none;">
    <span class="newAttendee">
        <br>
    <input type="text" name="attendee[xxx][city]">
    <input type="text" name="attendee[xxx][state]">
    <input type="text" name="attendee[xxx][zip]">
    </span>
</div>

</body>
```

I hope this is useful for others.

Thanks to all for the input.